# R: How does one use the expect_success function for unit tests?

Tags: r, testthat

I have an expression that I want to test using the `testthat` package. In the documentation for `expect_success` it states usage of the function to be

```
expect_success(expr)
```

where `expr` is an *expression that evaluates to a single expectation*.

For instance, with this code

```
test_that("Expectation succeeds", {
  x <- 1:10
  expect_success(mean(x)) 
})
```

I get the error

```
Error: Test failed: 'Expectation succeeds'
* no expectation used.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, while I was writing the question, I further experimented with the code and found that I didn't at first fully understand the documentation. This function is used to test **other** expectations. So, for the example used in the question, this works as expected

```
test_that("Expectation succeeds", {
  x <- 1:10
  expect_success(expect_type(mean(x), 'double')) 
})
```